# Black screen showing instead of LaunchScreen.xib

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, splash-screen

I'm trying to make my file LaunchScreen.xib show as the launch screen of my app. Whenever I run the app for the first time (where you run the app, and the simulator loads up for the first time), the splash screen is not shown.

There's one black screen before the simulator loads, but then there is a second black screen before my app loads. If I run the app again, after the simulator is loaded, the launch screen displays with no issue. However, if the black screen shows the first time, users will assume the app is not working, hence why this is a concern.

These are the settings I am using for my launch screen.

[image]

[image]

All help appreciated.

Comment: It might be that is just Xcode's fault when attaching its debugger and running the app. If you just have the app on the device, completely quit it and then start it again, does the screen show?

Comment: Ahh, you're right. When I quit the app completely, and then run it, the launch screen works. I suppose it may be an Xcode bug then. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is just Xcode's fault. While starting the app Xcode attaches its debugger and does some communication and a lot of other stuff. It is very possible that the launch screen is not displayed during that time or just for a split second.

If you just have the app on the device, completely quit it and then start it again, the launch screen should show up as expected.

Answer (score 0):

There is no issue. The simulator load with blackscreen, it's not belong to your application. (os loaded at that time). After simulator loaded os, it launches your app with your laucnh screen